# display none doesnt hide children?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble with `display: none;`

The idea is simple:

There are steps on my website, when we finish the first step we get to the next, and when we get to the next step, the previous step hides.

I have checked the JavaScript and it works fine; I saw the `div`'s `display` attribute is `none`, but its children are still there; I will give the JavaScript in case.

```js
const first = document.getElementById('first');
const second = document.getElementById('second');
const third = document.getElementById('third');

const stepNumber = document.getElementById('step-number');

const next_btn = document.getElementById('next-btn');
const prev_btn = document.getElementById('prev-btn');

stepNumber.innerHTML = '1';

prev_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  stepNumber.innerHTML = Number(stepNumber.innerHTML) - 1;
  updateStep();
});

next_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  stepNumber.innerHTML = Number(stepNumber.innerHTML) + 1;
  updateStep();
});

function updateStep() {
  console.log(stepNumber.innerHTML)
  switch (Number(stepNumber.innerHTML)) {
    case 0:
      console.log('here')
      location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/start/';
      break;
    case 1:
      console.log('first')
      first.style.display = 'flex';
      second.style.display = 'none';
      third.style.display = 'none';
      next_btn.innerHTML = 'Next';
      next_btn.id = 'next-btn';
      break;
    case 2:
      console.log('second')
      first.style.display = 'none';
      second.style.display = 'flex';
      third.style.display = 'none';
      next_btn.innerHTML = 'Next';
      next_btn.id = 'next-btn';
      break;
    case 3:
      console.log('third')
      first.style.display = 'none';
      second.style.display = 'none';
      third.style.display = 'flex';
      next_btn.innerHTML = 'Finish';
      next_btn.id = 'finish-btn';
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="margin-top: 0.5em;" class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
  <div id="first" class="d-flex flex-column" style="display: none;">
    <h4 style="margin-bottom: 1.2em;"><b>Create Your Account</b></h4>
    <input class="form-control m_textinput" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username-input">
    <input class="form-control m_textinput" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email-input">
    <div style="font-size: 14px; width: 25em;" class="d-flex flex-column">
      <span><b>Date of birth</b></span>
      <p style="font-size: 12px;" class="text-muted">This will not be displayed publicly. Even if this account is for a business, pet, or something else, you'll still need to verify your own age.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex">
      <select id="b-month-select-input" class="form-select m_selectinput" aria-label="Default select example">
      </select>
      <select id="b-day-select-input" class="form-select m_selectinput" aria-label="Default select example">
      </select>
      <select id="b-year-select-input" class="form-select m_selectinput" aria-label="Default select example">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="second" class="d-flex flex-column" style="display: none;">

  </div>

  <div id="third" class="d-flex flex-column" style="display: none;">

  </div>

  <button id="next-btn" class="mt-5 btn btn-light rounded-pill" style="width: 25em;" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I've converted your code into a snippet that can actually be run inside your question. Please review it because it has an error: `TypeError: stepNumber is null` when you run it. This is because there is no HTML element with the ID `step-number` in your code

Comment: @ChrisBarr im sorry, that code snipped is not intentional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a `d-flex` class which is styled as `display: flex !important` in Bootstrap, and as such overrides your `display: none`. Apply the inline style as `none !important` instead if you need to override the styling of `d-flex` class.

Or, better, don't mix inline styles and Bootstrap classes. I.e. either apply only the inline styles, without `d-flex`, or apply only the classes, hidding <div>s not via a style property, but by removing the `d-flex` and adding a `d-none` class.